# How to make all text content in HTML to be plain black color?

Tags: css, wpf, internet-explorer, hyperlink, webbrowser-control

So I'm opening locally saved webpages .mhtml on my computer in webbrowser on WPF.

I wish to make text on that page plain,

I've tried adding

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
a:link { color: #000000; text-decoration: none}
-->
</style>
```

Under `<HEAD>`...that made all my text black, but while viewing it in chrome, in wpf webbrowser is IE and in IE links are still blue. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a { color: #000000; text-decoration: none}
a:visited { color: #000000; }
```

This should work. :) `a:visited` defines the css that styles the links that have been clicked. As far as I have tested, it works on IE too.

Comment: not working for IE still, on chrome the text is black

Comment: You are hoping that it be black or blue?

Comment: I need all text in html to be black when I open it in IE thats it

Comment: try `a:visited { color: #000000; }`

Comment: Please when posting an answer, try to briefly explain what your code does for better clarity and future reference.

Comment: I appologise, i assumed the codes were pretty self-explainatory. I will do so in the future.

Comment: nope tried to add it under <HEAD> but didn't work .. the text still shows links blue in IE